# running python script with cron

Tags: python, django, linux, cron

hey guys, im trying to run a python script after every 5 minutes using cron, inside the script is a django import

```
import django
```

when running the crontab i get mailed the following error

```
ImportError: No module named django
```

this is what the crontab file looks like:

```
MAILTO=commonzenpython@gmail.com

*/5 * * * *  /usr/bin/python /Users/paulo/Desktop/ashtanga/ping/sender.py
```

do anyone of you know whats causing this ?
btw i do have django insalled version 1.2, python 2.6, and MacOX 10.6

EDIT:

$PYTHONPATH = isn't this the same as which python

python -v =

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84374, Aug 31 2010, 11:00:51) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
```

which python

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python
```

Comment: Potential repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487145/python-script-not-working-via-cron/4487291#4487291 and others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This boils down to the actual python interpreter in use at the time cron executes the script in all likelihood, so here's how to narrow that down:

Open up /Users/paulo/Desktop/ashtanga/ping/sender.py and see if there's a line at the top starting with '#!'. This is the version of Python that is invoked when you run the script at the command line *if you don't invoke it with an explicit interpreter*. So, if that line says "#!/usr/bin/python", and you run it at the command line like this:

```
$  /Users/paulo/Desktop/ashtanga/ping/sender.py
```

(Where '$' is the command line prompt)

Then /usr/bin/python is the interpreter binary being invoked. If the script works when you run it this way, then you want to make sure that /usr/bin/python is the interpreter being invoked by cron when it runs your job.

However, outside of an explicit Python interpreter indicated in a '#!' line (called a 'shebang' line in some circles), two other possibilities exist:

First, the shebang line might say '#!/usr/bin/env python', which means 'use whatever Python interpreter is the first one found when you search the directories in the user's $PATH environment variable'. You don't want to rely on that when you run from cron, so you want to specify an explicit path to a Python interpreter. You're already doing that, but you need to make sure that if you launch /usr/bin/python at the command line, it can successfully import django. If it can't, you need to find which one does, and specify that one in your cron job.

Second, there might be no shebang line at all in the script, in which case you also *must* specify an interpreter in your cron job. See above :)

Comment: its working now, i used the path given in which python, turns out django is not installed in the python version given by /usr/bin/env python  ,  thanks a lot everybody :P

Answer (score 5):

I want to addd one point to @Hank's answer.

cron doesn't have all the environment variables set as in the shell you use. Only `LOGNAME`, `HOME`, and `SHELL` are defined. (You can refer to "man 5 crontab" for more info.)

You can define `PYTHONPATH` environment variable in cron just as the way you defined `MAILTO`. So no shell wrapper is needed.

Comment: That's a good point about being able to define it in the crontab file like `MAILTO`. I find it cleaner to use a shell wrapper, but that's purely a personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the environment of your CRON job doesn't have a proper reference to your `site-packages` directory. You might try setting the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable in a shell wrapper around `sender.py`, or possibly adjusting `sys.path` from inside `sender.py`. Really, if you have a recurring task involving Django, you should probably look into [celery](http://celeryproject.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You probably have two versions of python installed and `/usr/bin/python` is not the one in which you installed Django.

Try to make `sender.py` executable by inserting the following line as first line of the file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

and chmodding it a+x. Then try to run it with `./sender.py`.

If it works, replace `/usr/bin/python /Users/paulo/Desktop/ashtanga/ping/sender.py` in the crontab with `/Users/paulo/Desktop/ashtanga/ping/sender.py`.

Comment: i have tried your solution, however it worked in the shell when i ran it with ./sender.py , but it threw the same error once  i put it in the crontab.

Comment: That's very strange. Can you update your question with your `$PYTHONPATH`, `which python` and `python -v` from the shell where the script works?

Comment: done i think the PYTHONPATH is the same as which python though