# crontab can not running python script

Tags: python, centos, cron

I use centOS, at command line, I execute `>./tv.py` script and it runs correctly.

But,  when I include into `/etc/crontab`,  entry `*/30 * * * *    /root/tv.py` ， it does not.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the head of script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: Does the file have executable file permissions?

Comment: You can also see [Running a Python Script using Cron?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486472/running-a-python-script-using-cron)

Comment: @BrendanAbel  Yes, I did  `chmod 777 tv.py` before.

Answer (score 2):

We need more information to troubleshoot this issue. Namely, you will need to monitor /var/log/syslog and spot errors regarding that cronjob. It is probably also good practice to output an error log for this job.

Comment: thank you tell me about the log information , it help me solved it.

Answer (score 2):

I just change the crontab to  `*/30 * * * * root python /root/tv.py`  and then it running , thanks everyone.